# Inquire option in github as a "project collaborator"

Tags: github

When making a pull request in GitHub you get some notification like so:

> This pull request can be automatically merged by project
>   collaborators. Only those with write access to this repository can
>   merge pull requests.

If you are a "trustworthy" contributor who closes issues and fixes bugs and implements features is there a way to "inquire" or ask to become a project collaborator?

I know the owner of the repository can manually add you as a project collaborator, I'm asking if there is any builtin mechanism on [github.com](http://www.github.com) to allow you to "ask" to become a project collaborator?  Or is it simply contacting the developer via email and asking?

I tried looking in various places including directly on the repo, my settings page, my profile, etc. but came up short handed.  Maybe I missed it or maybe it just does not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you are going to have to email him or her.

Comment: I figured but it would seem this would be a nice little feature on github.com don't you think?

Comment: I agree, would be nice to have a little more team management features. I would also like to be able to restrict people from committing to certain branches and merging specific branches.